# JGit: Symmetric Difference Log

Tags: git, jgit

How to [retrieve symmetric difference](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) log in JGit? Basically, an equivalent to the next git command:

```
git log br-1...br-2
```

It retrieves commits that are reachable from one commit but is not reachable from both.

The next code is working for me, but probably there is a better way:

```java
ObjectId br1 = repository.resolve("br-1");
ObjectId master = repository.resolve("master");

RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
walk.setRevFilter(RevFilter.MERGE_BASE);
walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(br1));
walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(master));
RevCommit base = walk.next();

Iterable<RevCommit> logs = git.log()
        .add(br1)
        .add(master)
        .not(base)
        .call();
```